# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Page: Complex model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I am struggling with data binding and Razor pages. I want a page to create bookings to collect all necessary data to post it to a Web API when everything is done.

On that page I want to collect necessary data for the booking and want to add x Booking Details to the Booking.

**Datamodel**

```
public class Booking
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Reference { get; set; }

   public List<BookingDetail> BookingDetails { get; set; }
}
public class BookingDetail
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int Pieces { get; set; }

   public string Marks { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to to is to create a create page for a booking.
So far I followed this instructions, which is working [Link](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-related-collections-to-a-complex-object)

This missing part is that I would like to add new Booking Details as well on the same Razor page.

So I want to see a list of all added booking Details and I want to have textboxes to add new booking Details.

My idea was to do the following, but I am receiving a `System.NullReferenceException` as Booking is null:

```
@page
@model Onlinebooking.Web.Pages.BookingModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Booking";
}

<h1>Booking4</h1>
<form method="post">
    Reference: <Input asp-for="Booking.Reference" /><br />
    Pieces: <input asp-for="Booking.BookingDetails[0].Pieces" /><br />
    Marks: <input asp-for="Booking.BookingDetails[0].Marks" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<form method="post" asp-page-handler="DeleteBookingDetails">
    @for (var i = 0; i < @Model.Booking.BookingDetails.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Booking.BookingDetails[i].Pieces)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Booking.BookingDetails[i].Marks)
    }
</form>
```

Is it possible to do all that on one page, or should I go in a different direction?

Comment: This is possible; you can even use templates to define a proper `EditorFor` ... btw, why the `-1` in `@Model.Booking.BookingDetails.Count()-1`?

Comment: It's probably hard because you are trying to use your data model as a view model.   They really should be different things (with probably many of the same properties).   Everything you see on the UI/View should have a property in the ViewModel, but not all of those properties will end up in your database.

Comment: @Stefan I see that the ```-1``` is a mistake and makes no sense. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo to add and delete BookingDetai:

cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
    <Input asp-for="Booking.Id" hidden />
    Reference: <Input asp-for="Booking.Reference" /><br />
    Pieces: <input name="Booking.BookingDetails[@Model.Booking.BookingDetails.Count()].Pieces" /><br />
    Marks: <input name="Booking.BookingDetails[@Model.Booking.BookingDetails.Count()].Marks" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" asp-page-handler="AddBookingDetails"/>
    <div hidden>
        @for (var i = 0; i < @Model.Booking.BookingDetails.Count(); i++)
        {
            <input asp-for="@Model.Booking.BookingDetails[i].Id" hidden />

            <input asp-for="@Model.Booking.BookingDetails[i].Pieces" hidden />

            <input asp-for="@Model.Booking.BookingDetails[i].Marks" hidden />


        }
    </div>
   
</form>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><label class="control-label">Pieces</label></th>
                <th><label class="control-label">Marks</label></th>
                <th><label class="control-label">Action</label></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < @Model.Booking.BookingDetails.Count(); i++)
            {
            <tr>
                <form method="post" >
                    <div hidden>
                        @for (var j = 0; j < @Model.Booking.BookingDetails.Count(); j++)
                        {
                            <input asp-for="@Model.Booking.BookingDetails[j].Id" hidden />

                            <input asp-for="@Model.Booking.BookingDetails[j].Pieces" hidden />

                            <input asp-for="@Model.Booking.BookingDetails[j].Marks" hidden />


                        }
                    </div>
                    <td>@Model.Booking.BookingDetails[i].Pieces</td>
                    <input name="Booking.Id" hidden value="@Model.Booking.Id" />
                    <input name="Booking.Reference" hidden value="@Model.Booking.Reference" />
                    <input name="BookingDetail.Id" hidden value="@Model.Booking.BookingDetails[i].Id" />
                    <td>@Model.Booking.BookingDetails[i].Marks</td>
                    <td><button asp-page-handler="DeleteBookingDetails">delete</button></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

cshtml.cs(I use simple data to test it):

```
   public class CreateBookingModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Booking Booking { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        //BookingDetail is used to delete BookingDetail 
        public BookingDetail BookingDetail { get; set; }
        public static int count;
        public ActionResult OnGet()
        {
            List<BookingDetail> list = new List<BookingDetail> { new BookingDetail { Id = 1, Pieces = 2, Marks = "m1" }, new BookingDetail { Id = 2, Pieces = 1, Marks = "m2" } };
            Booking = new Booking { Id = 1, Reference = "r", BookingDetails = list };
            count = 2;
            return Page();
        }
        public ActionResult OnPostAddBookingDetails() {

            Booking.BookingDetails[Booking.BookingDetails.Count()-1].Id = ++count;

            return Page();
        }
        public ActionResult OnPostDeleteBookingDetails() {
            Booking.BookingDetails.RemoveAll(b => b.Id == BookingDetail.Id);
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I learnt alot. But I have a problem deleting one line of the list.
When I delete by doing ```Booking.BookingDetails.RemoveAt(1);``` in ```OnPostDeleteBookingDetails``` I see strange behaviour. 
Could you please add the delete function to your example?

Comment: I have updated my answer to bind Booking.Id and the BookingDetail  you want to add or delete

Comment: I think your code is broken now. Adding and deleting is not working. I am sorry. I am not able to figure out how I can make it work...

Comment: You can get Booking Id  and  the BookingDetail you want to add or delete,and then you can use Booking Id to find the Booking in database,and add or delete the BookingDetail of it.I just write a demo to model binding the data needed  without writing  adding or deleting data from database.

Comment: Got you. I really liked your code adding the data to the model w/o writing it into a database as I dont have a need for it as I want to post the data to a webapi. Anyhow: after you revised your code adding data is not working nor deleting is. And I have no clue how to fix it. And we are so close to have a really nice solution which would totally fulfill my needs.
So is there any chance to delete data from added data from your first version of the code? I guess a problem is that when the data is "only" written into the model there are no IDs set yet...

Comment: Firstly,id is often be set in database automatically,and you didn't add id on page,so it don't have id.And now I set a static int to set id for it.I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple concepts I have had much difficulty with also in your question.

The first issue you are coming across is in the CSHTML.CS file. Initializing your variables will solve that problem.

```
public class BookingModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly DataDbContext _context;

    public BookingModel(DataDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; } = new List<Booking>();
    public Booking Booking { get; set; } = new Booking();
    public BookingDetail BookingDetail { get; set; } = new BookingDetail();

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Bookings = _context.Bookings.Include(x => x.BookingDetails).ToList();
    }
}
```

And on the CSHTML side I would slightly modify how you are referencing the labels and printing your FOR loops.

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="DeleteBookingDetails">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><label asp-for="BookingDetail.Pieces" class="control-label"></label></th>
            <th><label asp-for="BookingDetail.Marks" class="control-label"></label></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var booking in Model.Bookings)
        {
            foreach (var bookingDetail in booking.BookingDetails)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@bookingDetail.Pieces</td>
                    <td>@bookingDetail.Marks</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have not modified Booking or BookingDetail.

I believe you will be able to figure out the rest of your functionality from here.